# Popping from Stack returning equal sign before returning character provided

Tags: c++, char, stack

I'm writing an example of a stack using a character array in C++.

When accessing the stack as follows:

```
while (stack->notEmpty()){
    stack->display();
    stack->pop();
}
```

it shows that only the characters that belong in the stack are there:

```
+
2
3
---
+
2
---
+
---
(empty)
```

However, when trying to access the characters returned by the function, in this manner:

```
while (stack->notEmpty()){
    char c = stack->pop();
    cout << c << "\n";
}
```

it returns the characters:

```
═
3
2
+
```

This leads me to think there is something wrong with my function, but it works when I'm not storing the returned character.  I have made workarounds in my current code, but I'd like to know if anyone sees anything that could be causing this issue.

I create the stack using:

```
Stack *stack = new Stack(1024);
```

And access it via:

```
char pop(){
    if (!(top == 0)){
        char return_char = stack[top];
        --top;
        return return_char;
    }
    else{
        char return_char = stack[top];
        top = 0;
        return return_char;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts and help are appreciated!

Paste for full header [here](http://pastebin.com/vYLNJxQp)

Comment: Hard to tell without your entire code, but are you sure your manipulation of `top` is not off by one (i.e. the top of stack actually resides in `top-1`) ?

Comment: Yep!  The push function adds one to the top.  It's initialized at 0 when the program loads.
I can pastebin my Stack.h file if you'd like

Comment: Your function is over-engineered a bit. Try this version:
`char pop(){ return top ? stack[top--] : stack[top]; }`

Comment: @NickMedovich, yes, please pastebin your Stack.h

Comment: @SamProtsenko That causes an infinitely loop in my code.  I doesn't successfully pop the first item off the stack.
I'll pastebin my code so you can see how it's being used.

Comment: The paste is at the bottom of the page hyperlinked on "here"

Comment: `push` leaves `top` pointing to the first free element. But `pop` is written to assume that `top` points to the last assigned element. Keep your invariants straight.

Comment: You mean the push tells the program where it's supposed to look next, but pop doesn't keep up with it?

Comment: @NickMedovich: Did you actually try that? Because my version of `pop()` function has exactly the same behavior as yours, only it's much more shorter.

Comment: Imagine you start with an empty stack, and call `push('x')` once. Element at which index is now set to `'x'`, and what is the value of `top`? Now imagine you call `pop()`. Which element gets returned?

Comment: @SamProtsenko I did.  With the second implementation where I tried to return the characters, it caused an infinite loop.  With the first implementation, it returned what I wanted.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik my code, when starting at zero, will add to the stack, then increment by one.  Does this mean my push function is pointing to the next place where push should add a character instead of pointing to where the top entry on the stack actually is?

Comment: So `push` stores at `top`, then increments `top`. Shouldn't `pop` do exactly the reverse, then?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I'll re-implement that and get back to you and see if I'm still receiving the same character

Comment: On page, I do pop the top, then decrement the top